# How can I force spans to be on the same line as a div?

Tags: css, html

I have a simple structure of:

```
<div></div><span></span><span></span>
```

but I want to force them all on one line! at the moment, they appear:

```
<div />
<span /><span />
```

unfortunately, I HAVE to have the first element as a div; the div is acting as a bar from a bar chart (so rounded corners, width = jquery stuff, no content and block colour inside), the next span is the value the bar represents and the last span is what the value is associated to.

so I want

```
[____________] 25% ObjectA
[________________________] 50% ObjectB
[______] 12.5% ObjectC
[______] 12.5% ObjectD
```

and not

```
[____________] 
25% ObjectA
[________________________] 
50% ObjectB
[______] 
12.5% ObjectC
[______] 
12.5% ObjectD
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put the CSS property `display: inline-block` on the div to make it act like an inline element instead of taking up the whole line.

**Edit:**

@Mr_Green's suggestion to use the `after` pseudo-element to clear each line is absolutely necessary to prevent a broken layout.

Comment: Thank you, I feel all embarrassed now! to be fair, its pretty early in the morning now. Thank you, will tick when it lets me.

Comment: This works but sometimes the second bar will also come in line with the first bar if their widths are small.

Comment: @Mr_Green that's true, this is probably an appropriate use case for the `<br />` tag, although if he has zero control over the html, perhaps a float based layout would be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

The suggestion of Dylan will work but sometimes if one of the div's width is very less then the next div will come inline with this div element. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/SKWuW/1/). So, my suggestion is to use `:after` pseudo element which will be `display: block`. This pseudo element will be for the last span in every bar section.

```
div {
    /* width and height are just for example */
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
div+span+span:after {  /* last span element's pseudo element */
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/SKWuW/)

Answer (score 3):

At your span add the CSS property:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `<div>` elements default to `display: block`, which takes up all available width, you'll need to set it to `display: inline-block`. You'll also need to break the lines manually with a `<br>`, or do something fancy on the last `<span>` to make it fill the rest of the available space.

Alternatively, wrap each row in another block-level element (such as another `<div>`) to create new rows.